# How to pass arbitrary values into Nuxt (before it boots)

Tags: vue.js, aws-lambda, nuxt.js

I'm running Nuxt on Lambda, and starting it up like this:

```js
const { loadNuxt } = require('nuxt-start');

module.exports.render = async (event) => {
  const nuxt = await loadNuxt({ for: 'start' });
  const { html } = await nuxt.renderRoute(event.requestContext.http.path);

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: html,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html',
    },
  };
};
```

Within the Nuxt app, I need to access the user's IP address, but Nuxt's `context.req` object is missing (since Nuxt is not being loaded by a network request directly), so I'm not able to grab the user's IP address from there.

The Lambda event object *does* have it, however, in `event.requestContext.http.sourceIp`. Is there some way I can inject this value into the above load process so I can access it within Nuxt's `asyncData()` method?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! Solution:

```js
  const { html } = await nuxt.renderRoute(event.requestContext.http.path, {
    sourceIp: event.requestContext.http.sourceIp,
  });
```

And then the IP address is available within `asyncData`:

```js
  async asyncData({ params, $axios, $cookies, error, ssrContext }) {
    console.log('IP:', ssrContext.sourceIp);
    // ...
```